# What is the logical relationship of crypto files generated by cryptogen in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In the get started [example](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) , crypto-config files are generated by the cryptogen tool. 
[image: crypto-config files]

I'm not quite understand with the encryption mechanism and authorization methods between peers, membersrvc or orderers.

Is there any wiki about it or can anyone explain how these files are used in any scenes？

Answer (score 0):

Just appeared, "Membership Service Providers (MSPs): Setup & Best Practices" https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/msp.rst